# Asp.Net Web Api is not working in Godaddy server but its working fine in local

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am getting error when i run Web Api (www.example.com/api/values) in godaddy server it shows **(404 Not Found The requested document was not found on this server.)**. But its working fine in local.

I have manually uploaded the files using FTP(FileZilla) in Godaddy and also Godaddy server supports ASP.NET Hosting.

Below are the code using in Web Api:

ValuesController.cs

```
namespace Webapi {
 public class ValuesController : ApiController {
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Valueswebconfig.cs

```
namespace Webapi {
  public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

       // config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));


        //// Custom Formatters:
        //config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(
        //    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml"));

        //var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        //jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    }

  }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer></configuration>
```

Comment: try like this, www.example.com/api/api/values

Comment: Thank you Pranav, i tried like above like but its not working... Please advice

Comment: try this www.example.com/api/Values/Get

Comment: More than likely you need to set up your application on IIS on the server.

Comment: Above link also not working pranav. Hi, padraic thanks, but how to configure IIS in Godaddy server. I am running web api in Godaddy server...

Comment: Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy **Shared Hosting** does not support Web API as it can't serve the requested URL (extension less URL). Windows Shared Hosting (Plesk) on GoDaddy does not work well will API (even though it has support for .NET and IIS, etc). Check if you can access an index.html file on the public directory of your hosting. You can create an index.html, if you don't have one and deploy it to your public director on GoDaddy hosting.

You can go for a VM on GoDaddy or AZURE.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Open Plesk in your GoDaddy account and click on the virtual directory. Just create a virtual directory and move your API files there and you are done.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LNnK.png)